# After installing xserver-xorg-core laptop won't boot

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, xorg, xserver

So I was trying to figure out how to install the proprietary Intel drivers for my laptop and found I needed to install `xserver-xorg-video-intel`. When I tried installing that I was told I needed to install `xserver-xorg-core` first. So I installed both and rebooted and now Ubuntu won't boot. It shows the Ubuntu logo then the screen goes black.

I am in recovery mode now. I removed both packages. However it still won't boot. What can I do to get the GUI working again?!

Thanks

I am using the Dell XPS 13 developer edition with 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ubuntu-desktop` package should pull in all necessary packages for the GUI, including any Xserver packages that may have gone missing.